# Visual Studio 2019--Exception from HRESULT 0x80041fe4

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2019

Every time I try to create a new "ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)" project, as soon as I get to the page where I select from Empty, Web Forms, MVC etc and select Web Forms, I get a popup saying

`Exception from HRESULT: 0x80041fe4`

I'm able to continually try creating these with no luck. I've deleted the folder and retried, I've uninstalled Visual Studio and reinstalled it, all to no avail.

Comment: are you install VS 2019 online or offline installation package?

Comment: Okay, I seem to have the solution. Closing visual studio, then re-opening it and trying again, WITHOUT deleting the folder, solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Cora - I encountered the same issue and your steps worked. After VS2019 created the solution folder, I closed it and relaunched it. The second time through, creating the solution and project using exactly the same name it successfully created the solution and project.

Comment: Has anyone reported this bug to MS? It's still happening.

Comment: Same here. I get this error every time I try to create a new solution. If I let it fail, close VS, open VS, and try again, it succeeds.

Answer (score 12):

I encountered the same error when trying to create a C# console app project. I used the steps in JJ Lay's answer to work around the issue. To be clear, these are the steps that I used:

1. Attempt to create a C# console app project (for example, named "TestProj" in Visual Studio 2019
2. Encounter 'Exception from HRESULT 0x80041fe4'
3. Close Visual Studio 2019
4. Open Visual Studio 2019
5. Use the same exact steps and name as in step 1 (for example, "TestProj") and try to create the project again
6. Project is created successfully this time

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by closing closing open window and creating a new project in fresh visual studio

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error message 'Exception from HRESULT 0x80041fe4' when creating a C# NUint Project.
I tried the Steps mentioned by @Lars Passic without any success
I'm using Visual Studio Community 2022 .Net 7 Windows 10 OS with intel i9 Processor

1. Close all Visual Studio Processes
2. Opened the Visual Studio Installer
3. Click on More
4. Click on Repair
5. Restart the Computer after it Complete
6. Create the new Project

Project Successfully Created.

- This issue occurs after my computer shut down (unstable Power supply issue) when I was working on the project
- Tried to restore the files once reopened Visual Studio