# Creating a new project in Visual studio 2022 - error exception from hresult 0x80041fe1

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

[image: error image]

As you can see - attempted to create a standard project, and this error pops up.

I have re-installed Visual studio as well as googled for help - but no one seems to be able to provide a solution that actually works.

Comment: Does this workaround work around it? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64289292/visual-studio-2019-exception-from-hresult-0x80041fe4

Comment: It doesn't no - that was one of the first things I tried. @DaveS

Comment: @HansPassant I have tried multiple folders. It works completely fine on my work laptop. This is my personal machine. The only anti-malware I have is windows basic security.

Comment: @HansPassant `0x80041FE1` seems to be `VS_E_PACKAGENOTLOADED`. The question linked by Dave has `...1FE4` ("solution already open"), but here we have `...1FE1` instead.

Comment: @heapunderrun so, does that help with what the issue might be?